# MVC3 Razor View Project using VB.NET gives Syntax error in Error List window for all vbhtml pages

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC3 and Razor View engine, I created a VB.NET web application in VS 2010. This creates the default Account and Home Controller along with corresponding Action Views.

Now if I open any vbhtml file I get the following error message in the Error List window.

Error   50  Syntax error.   C:****\MVC3AppVB\Views\Account\LogOn.vbhtml    MVC3AppVB
(See screenshot here http://www.flickr.com/photos/7672540@N07/5469248676/)

Who ever this app compiles and runs without any problem. I tried to create the same project using C# and there is no error message in the Error List Window. 
Can anyone explain why this error message shows up only for VB and not for C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sure is annoying.  VB.Net/Razor just doesn't feel as natural as C#/Razor at this point, and little tooling bugs like this just make that more so pronounced.  Luckily this bug will be fixed in v.Next!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with MVC3 and webpage 1.0 tooling. This issue has been answered in [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8136).

Answer (score 1):

Probably some bug with the Intellisense. Try recompiling the project. Unfortunately the Razor Intellisense is far from perfect. I hope it will be improved in future releases of Razor.

Comment: I tried recompiling but the error is still there. I got the latest MVC3 RTM installed and I thought Microsoft would have resolved this error by now. Also I'm surprised no one else has reported this issue.